# How I can upload the complete directory Django?

Tags: python, django, directory, copy

I would like to upload the complete directory but I do not know how to do it.
Currently, I am able to opload more files at the same time.
But my wish is to copy and paste the reiter to my media directory in django.
How can I do this?

**Here is my form:**

```
from django import forms
class FileFieldForm(forms.Form):
    file_field = forms.FileField(
         widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
```

**vocii my view:**

```
def FileView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileFieldForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in request.FILES.getlist('file_field'):
                liens = str(settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
                myfile = f
                a = myfile.name
                b = myfile
                fs = FileSystemStorage(liens + "photo/")
                filename = fs.save(a, b)
    return render(request, 'photo/upload.html', {'form': form})
```

**here is my template:**

```
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  
  id="fileupload" type="file" name="file_field" multiple>
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: I don't understand: what exactly is the problem? Which part is not working as expected?

Comment: I want to browse my computer and select a folder. I would like to copy and paste this folder from my computer to my media folder that found on my django application.